# Foundation.h on Windows

Tags: windows, cocoa, foundation, cocotron

I know these questions have been asked before but everything suggest using GNUStep.  Is there a way to use Foundation without GNUStep?  This is also a learning question for me (like if it's possible to do by linking files or something)

I have Cygwin and gcc installed.  I got all the Libraries from CocoaTron as in here: http://code.google.com/p/cocotron/source/browse/

I added the library folder to the OBJC_INCLUDE_PATH and the C_INCLUDE_PATH and it doesn't complain about not being able to find Foundation.h anymore.

But I get other errors like:

```
$ gcc intro.m -o intro
In file included from /cocoa/CoreFoundation/CFBase.h:144,
                 from /cocoa/CoreFoundation/CFAttributedString.h:8,
                 from /cocoa/CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h:42,
                 from /cocoa/Foundation/Foundation.h:37,
                 from car.h:1,
                 from intro.m:2:
/cocoa/CoreFoundation/CFString.h:88: error: parse error before "va_list"
In file included from /cocoa/Foundation/NSAffineTransform.h:9,
                 from /cocoa/Foundation/Foundation.h:41,
                 from car.h:1,
                 from intro.m:2:
/cocoa/Foundation/NSGeometry.h:9:32: Foundation/NSObject.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /cygdrive/d/Allebrum Resources/C Libraries/cocoa/Foundation/NSAffineTransform.h:9,
                 from /cygdrive/d/Allebrum Resources/C Libraries/cocoa/Foundation/Foundation.h:41,
                 from car.h:1,
                 from intro.m:2:
```

I'm sorry for the novice question, I was just interested in running a few test and didn't want to install GNUStep.

I mean, a really simple example like:

```
//car.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Car : NSObject{
}
- (void)addGas;
@end

#include <stdio.h>
#import "car.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
printf("Hello");
return 0;
}
```

Yes, I know this example doesn't need objC ;)  I was just trying to follow along with a tutorial.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [the Cocotron's requirements page](http://cocotron.org/Info/System_Requirements) and [general information page](http://cocotron.org/Info), it seems that it only supports development on the Mac. What it provides is the ability to build a Windows- or Linux-compatible product… on your Mac.

So, as far as I can tell, at this time, you can't use Cocotron to develop on Windows. You'll still have to use GNUstep.